# Is this considered a contextual selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I think this is how a contextual selector is written correct?

```
p.notice {
margin:15px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Im just not sure how I would do this:
Using a contextual selector, change the color of italic text contained in h4 headings
to gold.

I know it would be something like this. I know something has to go before the h4 which makes it only change the italic text

```
h4 {
    color:gold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depends how the italic text is generated. If it's within `<em>` tags (which is likely), that would be

```
h4 em {
  color: gold;
}
```

Or `h4 i` when the italic text is done with `<i>` tags. Or 'h4 em, h4 i` to cover both possibilities.

If it's done with a class, you'd need to combine `h4` with that class, like `h4 .class_x` (not a child element).

What you have in your question (`p.notice`)  selects all `p`tags that have the class `.notice` *insinde* their `<p>` tag

Comment: So this is considered a contextual selector?

Comment: It was Actually done using the <i> tag. But I need to do make it so that it is a contextual selector. So how would I do that?

Comment: Okay, this assignment says to use a contextual selector tho to change the color of the italic text..but you are saying that not possible..Im confused.

Comment: `h4 i`*IS*  a contextual selector that does what you want. But you could just as well google that: https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-CSS2-971104/selector.html#h-6.4

Comment: So the way i have it written is considered a contextual selector?

Comment: @phillip swag: No, p.notice is not a contextual selector by CSS1's definition (if you could even call it one). It's a ridiculously old term that no one ever uses outside of homework assignments and online tests anymore, and it was written off for a very good reason (although the newest spec defines another term with similar, albeit not the same, meaning but a much more fitting name).